# Intermittent Mongo/JPA IllegalArgumentException parsing a geo native query

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa

I'm running `mongo-java-driver` as per

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and `hibernate-ogm-mongodb` as per

```
    <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
```

On executing a native query, using the below,

```
    String query = "db.%s.find({ 'location': { '$nearSphere': { '$geometry': { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [%s,%s] }, '$maxDistance': %s } } })";
    String format = String.format(query, getType().getSimpleName(), p.getX(), p.getY(), distance * 1000.0);
    try {
        Query nativeQuery = getEm().createNativeQuery(format, getType());
        return nativeQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("**** Location exception on query: "+ format);
        throw ex;
    }
```

I intermittently get the below exception. I can immediately run the same code, and receive a valid output.

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Error while parsing action 'Query/Optional/CliQueryOrJsonFindQuery/FirstOf/ParsedQuery/Db/Db_Action1' at input position (line 1, pos 3):
db.User.find({ 'location': { '$nearSphere': { '$geometry': { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [28.051258087158203,-26.135223388671875] }, '$maxDistance': 2.0 } } })
  ^

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot peek beyond the bottom of the stack
  at org.parboiled.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:79)
  at org.parboiled.support.DefaultValueStack.peek(DefaultValueStack.java:149)
  at org.parboiled.support.DefaultValueStack.peek(DefaultValueStack.java:144)
  at org.parboiled.support.DefaultValueStack.peek(DefaultValueStack.java:139)
at org.parboiled.BaseActions.peek(BaseActions.java:260)
```

This happens on multiple different document collections, but always intermittently. Literally repeating the action will cause a valid result to be returned.

I was previously on version `3.6.4`, but I was receiving similar errors.

Is there any indication of how I'm doing something wrong, or some sort of version conflict?

I've tried running in a loop to see if I could recreate it, but it only seems to happen once - could it be related to some sort of connection timeout after an idle period?

*Update*:

I tried creating a race condition by running two threads in parallel, and I did see exceptions, although slightly different.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: 
org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.query.parsing.nativequery.impl
.NativeQueryParseException: 
Cli query should match the format db.collection.operation(<arguments>)
at 
org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx
(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
```

I think that's convincing enough though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GitHub's page on Parboiled parser](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki/thread-safety) it is clear that:

> The parser classes created by parboiled for Java are not thread-safe.

... which could cause you problems when multiple threads are attempting to execute this query.

Try using named query instead. With annotations, it would be something like:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
  @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "findNearSphere",
    query = "db.:dbName.find({'location': { '$nearSphere': { '$geometry': { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [:xCoord,:yCoord] }, '$maxDistance': :distance } } }", resultClass = SomeResultClass.class
  )
})

getEm()
  .createNamedQuery("findNearSphere")
    .setParameter("dbName", "User")
    .setParameter("xCoord", 28.051258087158203)
    .setParameter("yCoord", -26.135223388671875)
    .setParameter("distance", 2.0)
  .getResultList();
```

... which hopefully would avoid using the Parser everytime you want to issue a query.

If you are not using annotations, there should be examples with these defined in XML mapping file.

(*please however keep in mind I had not tested this code and one question in my head is whether you would you have to escape colons in the native query*).

HTH

Comment: The query is built up dynamically each time though, so that should avoid threading issues?

Comment: I am not sure whether EntityManager once created has one instance of the native query parser or not... Could you run a test (perhaps very long test) of using just one thread issuing the query? Or could you try protecting `getEm().createNativeQuery()` by a lock (place it in `synchronized {}` block and run as usual to see whether it it still trips up on parsing of the query. If not, parsing is the problem. If it still fails, then let us know and ignore my answer.

Comment: Interesting - I have tried a long-running test on one thread that didn't cause any errors, I'll try kicking off two of them and see what happens.

Comment: I kicked off another thread, and saw an exception very quickly. The stacktrace was different, but I think it proves the theory. I'll go with the performance impact via the `synchronized` block for now, with the plan to drop JPA (there's literally no benefit) and just go with Mongo drivers / Gson when I have the time - thanks.

Comment: For clarification for future people: I can't go with the named native queries because as far as I've seen, I can't pass in a document collection name as a parameter, which is why I'd been constructing strings until now.